# Dynamic color resources acting strange in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml

In my application I have a bunch of resources defined in dictionaries, they all get merged into App.xaml, and everything works fine.  However I've been trying to add a second theme to my application.  I've got all the brushes defined in a default spot, and the colors defined per theme:

In the shared Brushes.xaml:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ForegroundBrush" Color="{DynamicResource ForegroundColor}" />
```

Then each theme has a Colors.xaml dictionary with all the colors defined:

```
<Color x:Key="ForegroundColor">#FF112233</Color>
```

A base dictionary ResourceLibrary.xaml merges all the styles, brushes, etc together then gets merged into App.xaml, and Colors.xaml gets merged into App.xaml by the theme manager (Infragistics, but I've also tried manually merging it).  Like this, nothing shows up.  However if I merge ResourceLibrary.xaml into my view, everything shows up on that one view.  When I don't merge it in and I can't see anything, I can still use the Live Visual Tree to find the controls, and they have all the correct styles applied and everything, including the correct brushes with their expected resource keys...  But then the color is always #00FFFFFF (which I assume is the default value for Color).  So it's able to find everything from App.xaml up until the color, but can't seem to find the color.

Here's another interesting thing to note...  If I merge ResourceLibrary.xaml into my window, and then host another user control on the window, the user control has access to all the colors EXCEPT ones that are being used on the host window.  If the brush was not used on the window, it shows up correctly on the user control, if it was used by the window then it shows up correctly on the window but in the user control it has the #00FFFFFF color.

I've been bashing my head against this for three days now and have gone full circle multiple times, I'm now completely out of ideas.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are the resource dictionaries for the other theme also being "merged" into the app.xaml with potential name collisions? Also are all the style templates of the controls bound back to "Foreground Brush" as a staticresource for Foreground at the template level?

Comment: The dictionary for the previous theme gets unmerged from App.xaml and the dictionary for the new theme gets merged in.  The styles are using DynamicResource for the brushes, but those appear to be working fine because when I use the Live Visual Tree it's got the right brush with the right name, but the brush's color is not set.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same/similar problem and figured it out. For anyone else having this problem, here is what I did:

I had to set the brush references in the styles as StaticResources, and the color references in the brushes as DynamicResources. Now when I swap themes (separate resource dictionaries with colors) everything updates correctly. Here is an example:

An implicit label style (note the ForegroundBrush is set as a StaticResource):

```
<Style x:Key="LabelStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource ForegroundBrush}" />
</Style>
```

The brush which the above style references:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ForegroundBrush" Color="{DynamicResource ForegroundColor}" />
```

These colors live in separate "theme" resource dictionaries which are swapped during run time to update the theme.

Light Theme (text color)

```
<Color x:Key="ForegroundColor">Black</Color>
```

Dark Theme (text color)

```
<Color x:Key="ForegroundColor">White</Color>
```